# Jslider is laggy after overriding paint method

Tags: java, swing, overriding, paint, jslider

After overriding the paintTrack and paintThumb method of my JSlider it lags if I drag its thumb.

I've replaced the track and thumb with images.  Any ideas how to solve the problem?

```
public class test {
private static JFrame frame;
private static JSlider slider;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    frame = new JFrame();
    slider = new JSlider();
    slider.setUI(new MySliderUI(slider));
    frame.add(slider);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1200, 720);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

private static class MySliderUI extends BasicSliderUI {

    private BufferedImage imgTrack;
    private BufferedImage imgThumb;

    public MySliderUI(JSlider slider) throws IOException {
        super(slider);
        imgTrack = ImageIO.read(new File("icon/track.png"));
        imgThumb = ImageIO.read(new File("icon/thumb.png"));

    }

    @Override
    public void paintTrack(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle t = trackRect;
        g2d.drawImage(imgTrack, t.x, t.y, t.width, t.height, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintThumb(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_OFF);
        Rectangle t = thumbRect;
        g2d.drawImage(imgThumb, t.x, t.y, null);
    }

}
```

}

EDIT:
Solved it, I also had to override the getThumbSize()

```
@Override
    protected Dimension getThumbSize() {
        return new Dimension(imgThumb.getWidth(), imgThumb.getHeight());
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new object every call? I'm guessing it's `Rectangle t = trackRect;` that's causing the problem.

Comment: I've declared the two Rectangle varibles now as class varibles, still doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work or lags? Not sure where thumbRect is defined in the code above to be honest.

Comment: still lags, the thumbRect and trackRect are from the super class, they hand over the position/size of the thumb/track.
Here's a screenshot how it looks like:
[link](http://imgur.com/1IjFX)